# Pass float in argument issue

Tags: c

I need pass float numbers and get it in program.

I tried a few ways but not success.  Here my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc>1)
    {
        printf("String \t[%s]\n", argv[1] ); // 222

        float floatNumber = atof( argv[1] );

        printf("Float \t[%lf]\n", floatNumber ); //0.000000

        printf("Float \t[%f]\n", floatNumber );  //0.000000     

        double doubleValue = atof( argv[1] );

        printf("Double \t[%f]\n", doubleValue );  //0.000000    
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is your input? what is your output?

Comment: my output is after comented line in prints..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all include `stdlib.h`, then change this

```
printf("%lf\n", floatNumber );
```

to

```
printf("%f\n", floatNumber );
```

the correct specifier for `float` in `printf()` is `"%f"`.

By omiting `stdlib.h` the compiler assumes that `atof()` returns `int`, which is the cause of the porblem.

You should also use a function that allows you to be sure that the conversion was performed correctly, instead of assuming that `argv[1]` is convertible, so for example a version of your program that will check for conversion errors would be

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc>1)
    {
        char *endptr;

        printf("%s\n", argv[1] ); // 222         

        float floatNumber = strtof(argv[1], &endptr);
        if (*endptr != '\0')
            printf("%s is not convertible to float\n", argv[1]);
        else
            printf("%f\n", floatNumber ); //0.000000            
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Finally**: to prevent this kind of problems, use compiler warnings, the compiler should have warned you about implicit function declaration, since `atof()` is implicitly declared in your program.

When a funciton is implicitly declared the compiler assumes that it's return value is `int`.

Comment: `%lf` should do the same as `%f`.

Comment: float strtof (const char* str, char** endptr); only two parameter allowed

Comment: hmmm it work.

strtof what is last paramter ? ( My monodev put a warning about more paramter )

it is right atof return int and double.. I need a float i need use strtof

Comment: @BrunoNovais Last parameter is a pointer to the characters that could not be converted, if all of them are converted, then it will only contain 1 character, the terminating nul byte `'\0'`

Answer (score 7):

You need `#include <stdlib.h>`.

The function prototype for `atof()` is declared in `<stdlib.h>`. Failure to include this results in the `atof()` function being assumed to return an `int`.

You would have known if you turned on compiler warnings. For example, gcc gives the following warning:

```
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘atof’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

Comment: After having seen the problem several times since I am on Stack Overflow, I still miss this, why would someone compile their program without checking all includes? and why not use warnings? I just noticed this was the problem, after thinking that the program was alright, why would it fail? ... Oh! `stdlib.h` is not included... +1

Comment: is exactly that.. 
but solution cant be used with atof.. atof return int i need a float.

but you have a good post thnkx.

Comment: @BrunoNovais What do you mean? `atof()` returns `double` if you include `stdlib.h`, it only returns `int` if you don't include `stdlib.h`

Answer (score 2):

You should add header file `stdlib.h` and `atof` return double type not float so try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc>1)
    {
        printf("%s\n", argv[1] ); // 222

        double floatNumber = atof( argv[1] );

        printf("%lf\n", floatNumber ); //0.000000

    }
    return 0;
}
```

besides, `atof()` is for both [c99 or c89](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atof):

```
zookeepdeMacBook-Pro:Desktop zookeep$ gcc test.c -o test
zookeepdeMacBook-Pro:Desktop zookeep$ ./test 222
222
222.000000
```

will works fine.

Comment: At least according to the Linux Programmer's Manual, `atof()` conforms to C99.